# Getting a fatal error while converting my python gui program to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

```
  I tried to convert my Tkinter gui program to .exe file using pyinstaller autowhatsapp.py --noconsole --onefile  command .But when i am launching my .exe file,i am getting a fatal error.
```

Can anyone help.
I am using Tkinter, threading,webbrowser, socket and pywhatkit library.
I am also using an icon file and a text file all stored in my python file directory.

I am one facing this problem in those programs where I imported additional modules and used files.Otherwise I successfully converted one of my gui program without getting any fatal error

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import *
import socket
import webbrowser


def is_connected():
    try:

        socket.create_connection(("1.1.1.1", 53))
        return True
    except OSError:
        pass
    return False

def callback(url):
   webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

def con_check():
   check = Tk()
   check.title("!ERROR")
   check.minsize(350,150)
   check.maxsize(350,150)
   
   conn_lbl = Label(check,text="Internet connection required\nCheck your settings",font=("Comic San MS",15,"bold")).pack(pady=50)
   
   
   
   check.mainloop()

  
def main():    
  

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Whatsapp Message Sender")
    root.minsize(500,500)
    root.maxsize(500,500)
    root.config(bg="#33FF99")
    root.iconbitmap("whatsapp.ico")

    info_text = """NOTES(Version 1.0.1)\n\n\n 
                      \n 1> Login into https://web.whatsapp.com/ from your default web browser,ignore if already done.
                \n 2> You can close the browser after logging in
                \n 3> Images, videos and docs sending feature will be coming in next update  
                \n 4> If message is not sent, then check the recipient number and try again.
                \n 5> After scheduling msg,you can minimize the app.
                \n 6> WARNING! Don't close the app after scheduling msg,we will notify
                \n you weather your msg is sent or not
                  """ 

    
    def user_info():
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title("How to use?")



        text = Label(top,font=("Comic San MS",10,"bold"),text=info_text)

        text.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e:callback("https://web.whatsapp.com/"))                 
        text.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)  

                     
        

    #Widgets
    info_btn = Button(root,text="?",font=("Comic San MS",10,"bold"),command=user_info,bg="red").place(x=470,y=5)
    ph_lbl = Label(root,text="Recipient's Whatsapp Number -",font=("Comic San MS",12,"bold"),bg="#33FF99").place(y=35,x=10)

    v = StringVar()
    v.set("")
    h = DoubleVar()
    m = DoubleVar()

    phone_no = Entry(root,font=("Comic San MS",15,"bold"),textvariable = v,bg="white").place(x=270,y=35)
    hrs_lbl = Label(root,text="Time(24 hr format)-" ,font=("Comic San MS",12,"bold"),bg="#33FF99").place(y=100,x=10)
    hrs_entry = Scale(root,font=("Comic San MS",10,"bold"),variable = h,from_=1,to=24,orient=HORIZONTAL,bg="#33FF99",bd=0,label="hrs").place(x=230,y=80)
    mins_entry = Scale(root,font=("Comic San MS",10,"bold"),variable = m,from_=1,to=60,orient=HORIZONTAL,bg="#33FF99",bd=0,label="mins").place(x=390,y=80)

    msg_label = Label(root,text="Type your msg-",font=("Comic San MS",12,"bold"),bg="#33FF99").place(y=150,x=10)

    msg_box = Text(root,height=10,width=40,font=("Comic San MS",11,"bold"))
    msg_box.place(y=150,x=170)
    error_lbl  = Label(root,bg="#33FF99",font=("Comic San MS",12,"bold"),fg="red")
    error_lbl.place(y=400,x=100)
    def threading():
      t = Thread(target=prt)
      t.start()
    def prt():  
         
        try:
          int(v.get())  
        except:

           error_lbl.config(text=" ERROR! Enter a valid ten digits Whatsapp number ")
              
        if len(v.get()) != 10:
            error_lbl.config(text="ERROR! Enter a valid ten digits Whatsapp number")
       
              
        else: 
                import pywhatkit as kit
                v_int = int(v.get())
                kit.sendwhatmsg(f'+91{v_int}', msg_box.get(1.0,END), h.get() ,m.get(),tab_close=True,wait_time=5)
                error_lbl.config(text=f'Msg has been sent to {v.get()} successfully')
                
        
    def clr():
      error_lbl.config(text="")
           
    send_button = Button(root,text="Schedule to send message",font=("Comic San MS",11,"bold"),bg="lightgreen",command=threading).place(x=160,y=350)
    error_clr = Button(root,text="CLEAR",font=("Comic San MS",10,"bold"),command=clr).place(y=460,x=220)
 
    root.mainloop()


if is_connected():
  main()
  
else:
  con_check()
```

Comment: Is there no further information stating what causes this fatal error?

Comment: Can you state the error? just copy paste it.

Comment: I've been using ```nuikta``` for this with pretty complex projects and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

After converting your code into executable file, i ran the executable file on a terminal to find what is your real error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "whatsapp.ico" not defined
[10780] Failed to execute script (Your Script Name)
```

Simply you have a problem because of your icon, your icon isn't on the right path otherwise your code is working perfectly fine.

To fix this error just run your executable file while your icon on the right path, but if it still doesn't work:

- import getcwd by: `from os import getcwd`.
- replace this line of code `root.iconbitmap("whatsapp.ico")` with `root.iconbitmap(f"{getcwd()}\\whatsapp.ico")`
- make sure you are running your executable file while the icon on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for help but I found a solution. By using auto-py-to-exe i can now create my .exe file and my app is working fine